# How do I find further solutions of the following IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'= |x|^{1/2}$ and given $x(0)=0$.

Two of the solutions given are $x_1(t)=0$ and $x_2(t)=t|t|/4$.

We are asked to find other solutions. I can't even get these to begin with, I was never good at ODEs. Also, why does this not contradict Picard's theorem? Is it because $x(t)$ is not continuous at $0$?

Comment: $x(t)$ is continuous at zero. The reason that Picar'd Theorem doesn't apply is that $|x|^{1/2}$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: I see. I'll try to prove that. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexS, Can you please also explain how to go about finding the solutions aswell?

Comment: I don't have time right now. Maybe if there is no answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is for example $$x_3 (t) =\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{      if } x<0 \\ \frac{t^2}{4} \mbox{ if } x\geqslant 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is there a way that can allow us to say how many solutions there are, and how to get to them?

Comment: I don't know such general method. I see that there are four solutions of this problem $\{ x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 \}$ where $x_4 (t) =-x_3 (-t) .$